# Are you allowed to retrieve sequence inside a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence, declaration

I want to be able to get teh sequence value and use the same value on several operations in a trigger to do an audit operation for a table. So when a table is updated, I want to get all the column that were updated. But I want to have them grouped as one when I register the changed column in the database. Is there a way to get a sequence number and store in a variable inside a trigger. The code that I was able to make keeps on getting PLS-00357.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_EMPLOYEE_CHANGED AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
 OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE  REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE   
    GROUPID NUMBER := SEQ_POPERATIONLOG_LOGSUBNO.NEXTVAL; 
BEGIN

   OPERATION('FIRST_NAME', GROUPID, :old.FIRST_NAME, :new.FIRST_NAME); 
 OPERATION('LAST_NAME', GROUPID, :old.LAST_NAME, :new.LAST_NAME);  
 OPERATION('ADDRESS', GROUPID, :old.ADDRESS, :new.ADDRESS);  
 OPERATION('TELEPHONE', GROUPID, :old.TELEPHONE, :new.TELEPHONE); 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer by using select into.

```
SELECT SEQ_X_LOGSUBNO.NEXTVAL INTO GROUPID FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 7):

Prior to 11g, the only supported syntax for getting a value from a sequence was:

```
DECLARE   
    GROUPID NUMBER ; 
BEGIN
   SELECT  SEQ_POPERATIONLOG_LOGSUBNO.NEXTVAL
   INTO GROUPID
   FROM DUAL;
   ...
```

One alternative solution would be to use NEXTVAL in the first INSERT statement and CURRVAL (i.e. the most recently assigned value *in this session*) for the others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 10g or older then you'd need to select the sequence next value from Oracle's dummy table DUAL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER TRG_EMPLOYEE_CHANGED 
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE  OR UPDATE 
ON    EMPLOYEE  
REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new  
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE        
   GROUPID NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT SEQ_POPERATIONLOG_LOGSUBNO.NEXTVAL
     INTO GROUPID
     FROM dual;

   OPERATION('FIRST_NAME', GROUPID, :old.FIRST_NAME, :new.FIRST_NAME);   
   OPERATION('LAST_NAME', GROUPID, :old.LAST_NAME, :new.LAST_NAME);    
   OPERATION('ADDRESS', GROUPID, :old.ADDRESS, :new.ADDRESS);    
   OPERATION('TELEPHONE', GROUPID, :old.TELEPHONE, :new.TELEPHONE);  
END;
```